# What is the average size of an Elastic Beat, ElasticSearch document?

Tags: elasticsearch, server, filebeat, heartbeat, metricbeat

I currently do a small research to know what kind of server I need.

Currently the only thing (for now) I need to calculate the average size of an [Elastic Beat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats).

The Beats I will use are:

- Metric Beat
  ([System data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-system.html), [Nginx](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-nginx.html), [MySQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-mysql.html) and [Apache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-apache.html))
- Heart Beat
- File Beat ([Apache2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-apache2.html), [Nginx](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-nginx.html) and [MySQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-mysql.html))

My question is:
Is there any way I can measure the average size of an Elastic Beat document, without needing to install Beats somewhere?

Comment: Simple answer NO as each setup is different and depends on your app logging, number of metrics in each metricset etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same and had to install and use it for a week. The problem is, that the beats are clever enough to only send changes - so it heavily depends on your servers and their load on how big the documents are.